# List of Linux Applications using openCV Face Detection

Tags: linux, opencv, embedded-linux

I need a list of any well known Linux applications that uses object detection specially face detection using openCV. I tried googling for such Linux application but couldn't find any. If anyone is aware of any Linux application that uses openCV, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for `digiKam`. It uses OpenCV and certain other libraries like `libkface` for face detection.

Check out official site of digikam : http://www.digikam.org/

Even one of their GSoC project idea in 2012 was to implement face recognition with the help of OpenCV : [Link](http://community.kde.org/GSoC/2012/Ideas#Project%3a_Face_Recognition)

Even the [`Libface`](http://libface.sourceforge.net/file/Home.html) library of KDE (which is also used in digiKam) uses opencv for some purposes.

You can find `libkface` source here : [Link](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/libs/libkface/repository)